# using fulltext searches in symfony2 applications using doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, full-text-search, innodb

Is there a way already to use fulltext searches and indices in symfony2 application? 
(using doctrine)

Most the answers I found were old (and said no), and then there was one who implemented it by extending doctrine (which I'd rather not do if I don't have to):
http://www.xsolve.pl/blog/full-text-searching-in-symfony2-2/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing what was suggested in the article I referenced in my question.
It works well so far.

Note that you need mysql version 5.6 and above in order to have fulltext support on innodb tables (doctrine uses innodb afaik)

Answer (score 3):

I would highly suggest to use Elastisearch for implementing search features. There is an excellent https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle bundle that can help you to automaticly update the data in Elasticsearch on Doctrine entity save. We have a great experience with this.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it, but I doubt I'll be able to use that in my current project.